# Is there an API to programmatically configure or start focus mode on Android

Tags: android

Android 10 introduced Focus Mode that can be used to temporarily block certain apps. I was wondering if there is an official android API to configure and/or turn on Focus Mode. I searched the forums and also checked the Android developers website but I could not find anything for this.

Comment: i edited to your question to say `I was wondering if there is an official android API to...` because i am assuming that's what you want to achieve, feel free to revert if i'm wrong

Comment: asking for an official android api probably (hopefully) won't get your question marked as off-topic, where if you're simply asking for an api it potentially might be misunderstood as asking for an api :)

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't an official API yet to develop for Focus Mode. Currently, it is only available as a feature to end users. Fingers crossed to get this API at this year's I/O maybe.